# How to create Indexing in Bangla with babel package

Tags: babel, indexing

I am encountering a problem regarding indexing in *Bangla* language in `memoir`. I am using `babel` package with the following setup (shown in code). But it didn't work at all.

**MWE:**

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage[english.bidi=basic,layout=lists.tabular]{babel}
\babelprovide[import, onchar = fonts ids]{bengali}
% \babelfont[bengali]{rm}[Renderer=Harfbuzz]{FreeSerif}
\babelfont[bengali]{rm}[Renderer=Harfbuzz,AutoFakeBold,AutoFakeSlant=0.3]{Kalpurush}
\babelcharproperty{`।}{locale}{bengali}

% bangla numerals
\babelprovide[maparabic,alph=alphabetic]{bengali}

\usepackage{imakeidx}
\makeindex

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

যুক্তরাষ্ট্রের ভাইস প্রেসিডেন্ট \index{ভাইস প্রেসিডেন্ট} হয়ে ইতিহাস সৃষ্টি করেছিলেন কমলা হ্যারিস \index{কমলা হ্যারিস}। আবারও ইতিহাস সৃষ্টি করলেন তিনি। এবার প্রেসিডেন্ট \index{প্রেসিডেন্ট} হলেন কমলা। এই প্রথম কোনো নারী যুক্তরাষ্ট্রে প্রেসিডেন্টের ক্ষমতা পেলেন।

{যুক্তরাজ্যের}\index{যুক্তরাজ্যের} গণমাধ্যম বিবিসির খবরে বলা হয়েছে, মার্কিন প্রেসিডেন্ট জো বাইডেনের নিয়মিত স্বাস্থ্য পরীক্ষা অংশ হিসেবে গতকাল শুক্রবার কোলোনোস্কপি \index{কোলোনোস্কপি} করা হয়। এ সময় প্রেসিডেনশিয়াল ক্ষমতা দেওয়া হয়েছিল কমলাকে। ৫৭ বছর বয়সী কমলা প্রেসিডেন্ট হয়েছিলেন ৮৫ মিনিটের জন্য।

জো বাইডেনের যখন কোলোনোস্কপি করা হচ্ছিল, তখন তাঁকে চেতনানাশক দেওয়া হয়। তাই তিনি ক্ষমতা হস্তান্তর করেছিলেন কমলার কাছে। এ চিকিৎসা কার্যক্রম শেষে বাইডেনের চিকিৎসক \index{চিকিৎসক} কেভিন ও’কনর এক বিবৃতিতে বলেন, তাঁর স্বাস্থ্যের অবস্থা এখন ঠিকঠাক। তিনি এখন নিয়মিত দায়িত্ব পালনের জন্য প্রস্তুত।

\printindex

\end{document}
```

How can I make an Bangla index of the document?

Comment: Try with `mapdigits` instead of `maparabic`. There is a short explanation here: https://latex3.github.io/babel/guides/locale-bengali.html#counters . By the way, if you aren’t using an RTL language, remove `bidi=basic,layout=lists.tabular`.

Comment: mapdigits makes all bangla numbering in English which I don't want. I need to make all numbering in bangla for enumerate, contents etc.

Comment:  I’ve just realized the main language is `english`, but from your comment it seems the main language should actually be Bangla, right?

Comment: @JavierBezos Yes, it should be Bangla.

Comment: What did you run to create the index? And what error did you get? The linked question refers to xindy. Do you want to use that, or makeindex? Or some other index creator? Or maybe your question is: How to create an index in the first place?

Comment: @Cicada, Your are tight.

Comment: Info: When running with the imakeidx default setting (=use makeindex), the .ilg (index log file) says: "!! Input index error (file = bangla-index.idx, line = 1):  -- Illegal page number ১." etc. Is your .ilg file the same? Does your .idx file have content? Is the .ind file empty (=0 bytes)?

Comment: @Cicada The file contains no info (0 bytes).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Updated answer**

With `imakeidx` package calling `texindy` program using custom index style file:

[image: index bangla style]

Create a xindy index style file `.xdy` called `general.xdy` with this content:

```
(define-alphabet "bangla-numbers"
                   ("০" "১" "২" "৩" "৪" "৫" "৬" "৭" "৮" "৯"))
                   
(define-location-class "page-numbers" ("bangla-numbers") :min-range-length 3)
(define-letter-group "অ")
(define-letter-group "আ" :after "অ")
(define-letter-group "ই" :after "আ")
(define-letter-group "ঈ" :after "ই")
(define-letter-group "উ" :after "ঈ")
(define-letter-group "ঊ" :after "উ")
(define-letter-group "ঋ" :after "ঊ")
(define-letter-group "ঌ" :after "ঋ")
(define-letter-group "এ" :after "ঌ")
(define-letter-group "ঐ" :after "এ")
(define-letter-group "ও" :after "ঐ")
(define-letter-group "ঔ" :after "ও")
(define-letter-group "ক" :after "ঔ")
(define-letter-group "খ" :after "ক")
(define-letter-group "গ" :after "খ")
(define-letter-group "ঘ" :after "গ")
(define-letter-group "ঙ" :after "ঘ")
(define-letter-group "চ" :after "ঙ")
(define-letter-group "ছ" :after "চ")
(define-letter-group "জ" :after "ছ")
(define-letter-group "ঝ" :after "জ")
(define-letter-group "ঞ" :after "ঝ")
(define-letter-group "ট" :after "ঞ")
(define-letter-group "ঠ" :after "ট")
(define-letter-group "ড" :after "ঠ")
(define-letter-group "ঢ" :after "ড")
(define-letter-group "ণ" :after "ঢ")
(define-letter-group "ত" :after "ণ")
(define-letter-group "থ" :after "ত")
(define-letter-group "দ" :after "থ")
(define-letter-group "ধ" :after "দ")
(define-letter-group "ন" :after "ধ")
(define-letter-group "প" :after "ন")
(define-letter-group "ফ" :after "প")
(define-letter-group "ব" :after "ফ")
(define-letter-group "ভ" :after "ব")
(define-letter-group "ম" :after "ভ")
(define-letter-group "য" :after "ম")
(define-letter-group "র" :after "য")
(define-letter-group "ল" :after "র")
(define-letter-group "শ" :after "ল")
(define-letter-group "ষ" :after "শ")
(define-letter-group "স" :after "ষ")
(define-letter-group "হ" :after "স")
(define-letter-group "ৎ" :after "হ")
(define-letter-group "ড়" :after "ৎ")
(define-letter-group "ঢ়" :after "ড়")
(define-letter-group "য়" :after "ঢ়")
(define-letter-group "ৠ" :after "য়")
(define-letter-group "ৡ" :after "ৠ")
(define-letter-group "০" :after "ৡ")
(define-letter-group "১" :after "০")
(define-letter-group "২" :after "১")
(define-letter-group "৩" :after "২")
(define-letter-group "৪" :after "৩")
(define-letter-group "৫" :after "৪")
(define-letter-group "৬" :after "৫")
(define-letter-group "৭" :after "৬")
(define-letter-group "৮" :after "৭")
(define-letter-group "৯" :after "৮")
```

Invoke the style file with the module option switch (`-M general`) when `\makeindex` runs:

```
\makeindex[program=texindy,columns=2,columnseprule,options=-C utf8 -M general]
```

Compile with lualatex with the shell escape on (so that texindy can read the `.idx` file produced by latex and write to the `.ind` file).

MWE

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\makeindex[program=texindy,columns=2,columnseprule,options=-C utf8 -M general] 
\usepackage{babel}
\babelprovide[import, onchar = fonts ids]{bengali}
\babelfont[bengali]{rm}[Renderer=Harfbuzz,AutoFakeBold,AutoFakeSlant=0.3]{Kalpurush}
\babelcharproperty{`।}{locale}{bengali}
% bangla numerals
\babelprovide[maparabic,alph=alphabetic]{bengali}


\begin{document}

যুক্তরাষ্ট্রের ভাইস প্রেসিডেন্ট \index{ভাইস প্রেসিডেন্ট} হয়ে ইতিহাস সৃষ্টি করেছিলেন কমলা হ্যারিস \index{কমলা হ্যারিস}। আবারও ইতিহাস সৃষ্টি করলেন তিনি। এবার প্রেসিডেন্ট \index{প্রেসিডেন্ট} হলেন কমলা। এই প্রথম কোনো নারী যুক্তরাষ্ট্রে প্রেসিডেন্টের ক্ষমতা পেলেন।

{যুক্তরাজ্যের}\index{যুক্তরাজ্যের} গণমাধ্যম বিবিসির খবরে বলা হয়েছে, মার্কিন প্রেসিডেন্ট জো বাইডেনের নিয়মিত স্বাস্থ্য পরীক্ষা অংশ হিসেবে গতকাল শুক্রবার কোলোনোস্কপি \index{কোলোনোস্কপি} করা হয়। এ সময় প্রেসিডেনশিয়াল ক্ষমতা দেওয়া হয়েছিল কমলাকে। ৫৭ বছর বয়সী কমলা প্রেসিডেন্ট হয়েছিলেন ৮৫ মিনিটের জন্য।

জো বাইডেনের যখন কোলোনোস্কপি করা হচ্ছিল, তখন তাঁকে চেতনানাশক দেওয়া হয়। তাই তিনি ক্ষমতা হস্তান্তর করেছিলেন কমলার কাছে। এ চিকিৎসা কার্যক্রম শেষে বাইডেনের চিকিৎসক \index{চিকিৎসক} কেভিন ও’কনর এক বিবৃতিতে বলেন, তাঁর স্বাস্থ্যের অবস্থা এখন ঠিকঠাক। তিনি এখন নিয়মিত দায়িত্ব পালনের জন্য প্রস্তুত।

\printindex

\end{document}
```

---

*Original answer*

The situation is bit clearer now - I got this to work, with plain `babel`, and `mapdigits` option, and running Lualatex with shell escape - but page numbers are arabic:

[image: index]

MWE

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage{babel}
\babelprovide[import, onchar = fonts ids]{bengali}
% \babelfont[bengali]{rm}[Renderer=Harfbuzz]{FreeSerif}
\babelfont[bengali]{rm}[Renderer=Harfbuzz,AutoFakeBold,AutoFakeSlant=0.3]{Kalpurush}
\babelcharproperty{`।}{locale}{bengali}

% bangla numerals
\babelprovide[mapdigits,alph=alphabetic]{bengali}

\usepackage{imakeidx}
\makeindex

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

যুক্তরাষ্ট্রের ভাইস প্রেসিডেন্ট \index{ভাইস প্রেসিডেন্ট} হয়ে ইতিহাস সৃষ্টি করেছিলেন কমলা হ্যারিস \index{কমলা হ্যারিস}। আবারও ইতিহাস সৃষ্টি করলেন তিনি। এবার প্রেসিডেন্ট \index{প্রেসিডেন্ট} হলেন কমলা। এই প্রথম কোনো নারী যুক্তরাষ্ট্রে প্রেসিডেন্টের ক্ষমতা পেলেন।

{যুক্তরাজ্যের}\index{যুক্তরাজ্যের} গণমাধ্যম বিবিসির খবরে বলা হয়েছে, মার্কিন প্রেসিডেন্ট জো বাইডেনের নিয়মিত স্বাস্থ্য পরীক্ষা অংশ হিসেবে গতকাল শুক্রবার কোলোনোস্কপি \index{কোলোনোস্কপি} করা হয়। এ সময় প্রেসিডেনশিয়াল ক্ষমতা দেওয়া হয়েছিল কমলাকে। ৫৭ বছর বয়সী কমলা প্রেসিডেন্ট হয়েছিলেন ৮৫ মিনিটের জন্য।

জো বাইডেনের যখন কোলোনোস্কপি করা হচ্ছিল, তখন তাঁকে চেতনানাশক দেওয়া হয়। তাই তিনি ক্ষমতা হস্তান্তর করেছিলেন কমলার কাছে। এ চিকিৎসা কার্যক্রম শেষে বাইডেনের চিকিৎসক \index{চিকিৎসক} কেভিন ও’কনর এক বিবৃতিতে বলেন, তাঁর স্বাস্থ্যের অবস্থা এখন ঠিকঠাক। তিনি এখন নিয়মিত দায়িত্ব পালনের জন্য প্রস্তুত।

\printindex

\end{document}
```

Comment: It is actually that Javier suggested in the comments, but I have other things like enumerate, contents, etc. that must be in Bangla. So, is it possible to make the page numbers (all others numbers as well as) written in Bangla in index page and main content?

Comment: @mmr I expect so. To make it faster and easier so that those who may know the answer can actually help, edit the question to make it clearer what the issue is and what outcome you want to achieve and from what starting point; or ask a separate question. One question per question. "didn't work at all" is not informative, and asking a question in the comments is not where people would usually go to see what the question is. As to the digits, I will look at the babel manual to see how it is done; as to which index program to run, I suspect a unicode-aware one is needed (not makeindex program).

Comment: @mmr upated answer with a texindy solution

Comment: I will be more careful about asking questions. Thank you, anyway. It worked for me, now.